# accessing phpmyadmin and web pages on cloned server

Tags: ip, url, clone, phpmyadmin

I created a clone of my server and would like to use phpmyadmin to trim down the mySQL databases on the clone. Can't figure out how to access it. 
On my live server, the URL is: http://mydomain/db12/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=......etc
Is there any way to use the clone's IP addr and invoke its copy of phpmyadmin, without edit config files or any other changes?

Also, same question for serving web pages from the clone using just the IP addr?
Debian server, using virtual servers via VirtualMin. Path to each of several sites contained on the server is like: home/myDomain/public_html/

In case more details help: I'm using a cloud host (Digital Ocean). I did a shapshot of the live server, and used it to create a new droplet. I'm not going to keep this clone and have not create any DNS entries, so want to do what I need to do with it, using only the IP address, if possible. I'd like to trim the databases and create a master snapshot (backup) that I can then use to create several smaller clones in order to experiment with load balancers, db replication, etc in preparation for being able to scale up in the future, as well as improve performance now.

Comment: Well, have you tried replacing `mydomain` with the IP?

Comment: yes. I get this error:
"The requested URL /db12/phpmyadmin/index.php was not found on this server."

And for web pages, just using the IP gives the Apache2 Debian Default Page

Since this is temporay server, if the actual IP helps, it's: 159.203.73.174

Comment: I did a "locate" to find the actual path to the db12 directory and tried using this: 159.203.73.174/home/mydomain/public_html/db12/phpmyadmin/… as well as 159.203.73.174/mydomain/public_html/db12/phpmyadmin/… (no "home"), but get the same "not found" error.

Comment: are you trying to access your server from outside if yes then try accessing it from private/local ip and check results, may be your firewall doing some forwarding

Comment: "just using the IP gives the Apache2 Debian Default Page"

Answer (score 1):

Might be some VHost redirection/rewrite thing. Have you tried to change the DNS name to the IP address of the clone (temporarily, e.g. in the `hosts` file of the client)?

Edit:

Should that also fail, you might use other means to connect to MySQL, e.g. [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). If you don't want the MySQL service to be publicly reachable, consider an SSH tunnel. (That's how I administer MySQL database as I don't like having to install (and use) phpMyAdmin and Workbench is more comfortable than plain console.)